# How do I test for player 1/player 2/player3/ etc in a scoreboard?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Minecraft, when displaying a scoreboard as "list" it will show [1] to the left of the person who is on the top of the list. I would like to know how I can test for who has the [1] and [2] and [3]. This is because if I do a individual command for each number, I can prevent commands from affecting the whole server. If you want to provide alternatives, I will accept tag commands aswell like a system so that each player gets their own tag without 2 players having the same thing, this is all I need to know. And multiplayer compatable as this is for a server.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a score (or tag) to each player then use selector criteria to limit command chains to specific players.

Example:

```
/scoreboard objectives add team
/scoreboard players set @p team 1
/execute @p[scores={team=1}] ~~~ clear cobblestone
```

You'll have to invent your own scheme/redstone to get the players to assign themselves specific tags/scores.

Comment: any idea how I can do that? I had a feeling I'd need to do that kind of thing. But once I manage to get everyone sepperate tags like 1 player has tag=P1,p2,p3 etc. When they leave, what if they join back and then 2 people have the tag

Comment: A simple way is to have a spawn where people pick teams/positions by stepping on pressure plates. Teleport them to the game area as soon as they've chosen. Tags and scores are persistent so you don't need to worry about it after assignments are chosen.

Comment: I actually did think about that, however if someone picks the player 3 pressure plate, and leaves. then someone else joins and also picks player 3, the person when joining back will then still have player 3.

Comment: You could do something to disable the teleporter when a player picks it, such as setblocking-ing it up or something so they're one-time use.

Comment: You obviously didn't understand what I meant

Comment: Maybe not, but if you don't clarify I can't help you. Your concern seems to be two players being able to pick the same player number/position. How does making the teleporter/chooser one-time-use not address that problem?

Comment: I clarified pretty well, I said that the issue with it is that, when one player picks the player 1 area, and that get's blocked off, when they leave the game. It will open again, and another player can choose it. However by doing so, if the other player joins back both will have the same tag. I don't quite see how that can be missunderstood
This is for a multiplayer game, never once have I stated 2 players only.
You don't seem to get it.
Why humor the question if you don't have an answer?

Comment: You don't seem to understand what I was saying. Don't "unblock" the portal when they leave. Ever. That's what one-time-use means. When they re-join they will still have the player they chose and no new players can ever pick that player again, they need to pick a different player. Each player position will have its own teleporter.

Comment: @Thisisatempaccountforanswers if this answer worked for you after all, consider accepting it as it will mark it as accepted and award the answerer.